# python unittest own exception assertRaises

Tags: python, unit-testing

i'm having problem with unit test that asserts raising my own exception. Problem is that test always fails. And I don't know why. Here are my project files:

```
foo
 |-  __init__.py
 |-  exceptions.py
 |-  foo.py
tests
 |-  __init__.py
 |-  test_foo.py
```

exceptions.py

```
class MyException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, msg=None):
        if msg is None:
            msg = "An error occurred"
        super(MyException, self).__init__(msg)
```

foo.py

```
from exceptions import *


class Foo:
    def bar(self):
        raise MyException
```

test_foo.py

```
from unittest import TestCase
from foo.foo import Foo
from foo.exceptions import MyException


class TestFoo(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.foo = Foo()

    def test_bar(self):
        with self.assertRaises(MyException):
            self.foo.bar()
```

When I run the test, it fails and script outputs this in console:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "...\lib\unittest\case.py", line 605, in run
    testMethod()
  File "...\tests\test_foo.py", line 14, in test_bar
    self.foo.bar()
  File "...\foo\foo.py", line 8, in bar
    raise MyException
exceptions.MyException: An error occurred



Ran 1 test in 0.002s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

When I change MyException to Exception in test on line 13, it works. But I wanna test it for specific exception. Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: I'm just guessing, but try `raise MyException()`. You never instantiate your exception that you want to raise. Your code is trying to raise the `MyException` type rather than an instance of `MyException`.

Comment: Try having `Foo.bar` raise `MyException()` instead of `MyException`. `MyException` is not an instance of `Exception`, yet `MyException()` is.

Comment: thanks guys for quick response, but it didn't help, the test still fails

Comment: @byxor: `raise MyException` is equivalent to `raise MyException()`; Python will automatically construct an instance if you provide a class to `raise`.

Comment: What Python version is this, and what does your `sys.path` look like during this test? It looks like you've screwed up your import path, causing `exceptions.py` to be visible as both `exceptions` and `foo.exceptions`.

Comment: @user2357112 Python 3.6.4, ok... when I use "from foo.exceptions import *" instead of "from exceptions import *" it works... thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing

```
from exceptions import *
```

to

```
from foo.exceptions import *
```

in foo.py file.